# Problem in Installing Wordpress

Tags: mysql, php, configuration, installation, wordpress

I try to install Wordpress in a Windows Client with `WebPI` which provided by Microsoft.

I had tostop installation process 3 time and installing PHP and mysql Extention manually.
but everytime I continue setup by `WebPi` andfinally it show me a success message.

But when I try to see installed wordpress in my client I see this

`Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.`

I asked it in [StackOverFlow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003919/problem-in-installing-wordpress/3005775#3005775) but I couln't get the right answer.

I install everything in `**C:\Program files\**` so these are the location

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1

C:\Program Files\Php

C:\Program Files\ext

mysql root password: admin

wordpress database : wordpress

wordpress database password : 123

[**here is my php.ini**](http://codepaste.net/hynepe)

Comment: What is the path to php_mysql.dll? Is it correct in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

What if you uninstall PHP and reinstall it to C:\PHP?

I've seen problems when PHP is installed to a path that includes a space.